# how to wait a certain time for a keypress in c#?

Tags: c#, console

I'm currently writing a console application in c# and I was wondering if it was possible to set up the Console.ReadKey() (or similar) in such a way that it would wait a certain amount of time, say 100ms, for a key press, then if no keypresses are detected, continue executing code?
Thank you

Comment: You may want to reconsider 100ms : https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime :D But I guess that was just meant to be "some arbitrary value that we'll figure out later", right?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do it with combination of `Semaphoreslim` and `Task.Run`:

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

var consoleTask = Task.Run(() => {
    Console.ReadKey();
    semaphore.Release();
    });

await semaphore.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

Console.WriteLine("End of waiting");
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey()).Wait(100);
```